# Is there a wrapper to develop a plugin for WordPress and Prestashop in generic code?

Tags: plugin-development, pages, hooks

I'm looking for a wrapper or other tool that lets me develop a plugin for both WordPress and Prestashop in one go. So that I can write generic code to create a page, and have hooks to run on page load or helpers to call the database. And this wrapper would call the specifics needed for WP/PS.

I found https://youtu.be/exbCiGWwsro, but the maker states they stopped with it. Assuming it was hard work.

Does someone know if this exists?